# Log in and Sign Up to a Salesforce Community from an External System

Tags: community, single-sign-on, login, saml

I have a scenario where the customer can sign up/login from an external ecommerce system to a salesforce community with SSO and land on the community.
How can i achieve this? Salesforce as Identity provider and...?
I'm missing some parts.
in few words,the need is to login to salesforce from the external ecommerce.

Comment: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/headless-identity-basics

Comment: Not what i meant. The user need to login/register using SSO from the 3rd app and land on the community page

Comment: Welcome to SFSE.  Please take a moment to read [ask] and take the [tour]. 
 Sounds like your external system will be the SSO identity provider and Salesforce  will be the service provider.  You can configure Experience Cloud for SSO service provider,  you can search for SF documentation for that config.

Comment: ...and the phrase `login SLASH register` implies you need to think about this again.

Comment: @identigral you are right im using the wrong set of words to describe the question. I'm using a translator and It's not the best. They want to use salesforce as Identity provider and avoid to login twice (once from the e-commerce,and again into salesforce.) And from the e-commerce,they want to Land on the community.